Power Query M formula, replace delimited value within the same column
In reference to Power Query in Power BI. M formulas.
We have columns DATA 2 and DATA 3, we would like to replace the values in DATA 2 with the last index item of the column value, delimiter is ..
Next, for DATA 3 column, we would like to replace the values in DATA 3 with everything after the second delimiter of ..
The original DATA 2 and DATA 3 columns looks like this:

So for DATA 2, we got this code:
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Replaced Value", "DATA 2", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({"."}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"DATA 2.1", "DATA 2.2"}),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{"DATA 2.1"}),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns1",{{"DATA 2.2", "DATA 2"}}),

First part of question, is there a cleaner method so not to create two columns and deleting columns? We do want to replace the values of the column DATA 2 with the M formula results, and also for DATA 3.
Second part of question, for DATA 3 column, the number of return fields of the delimiting is not consistent. Some DATA 3 fields have 3 or 4 up to even 6 returned delimited fields.
For example DATA 3, the value could be 10.02.03.03 or it could be 10.01.05.03.07. The desired replacement value for these examples would be 03.03 and 05.03.07. Basically, removing the first two delimited values.
We have been trying this M function:
Text.AfterDelimiter("10.03.06.02", "-", 1)

As always any help is greatly appreciated. Another quick question, how to mark a response as "accepted" answer here? I used to see it but I cannot find it any more.
Thank you.

For data 2 you can try Extract Text after delimeter

For data 3 you can try the similar way


Much easier than splitting!

Would this work?
let 
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "Table1"]}[Content],
    transform2 = Table.TransformColumns( 
  Source, 
  { "Data2", if true then each List.Last(Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(".", QuoteStyle.Csv)(_)) else _ }),
  transform3 = Table.TransformColumns( 
  transform2, 
  { "Data3", if true then each Text.Combine(List.RemoveFirstN(Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(".", QuoteStyle.Csv)(_),2), ".") else _ })
 in
    transform3


